# Puppet agent: provider git is not functional on this host

Tags: windows, git, puppet

I been trying to fix this for a couple of days but no succsses yet, hope you can help me out:

What I have to do is to daily clone specific branchs of the company's git repo to specific (windows) vm's on the server.

For learning  matters, right now im just trying to clone the master branch in a folder on my Desktop.

Two important observations:

1 - I know that git is installed on the puppet agent

2 - The repository  doesnt have passphrase and the private key (ssh) is well allocated on the windows agent.

Now the code i have:

```
vcsrepo{ "C:\{Name of the win agent user}\Desktop\folder":
    ensure => present,
    provider => git,
    source =>'git@scm.example.com.br:controle_versoes.git',
}
```

When I run windows agent I receive the following message:

> Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[{nameoftheagent}]/Vcsrepo[C:\User{Name
>   of the win agent user}\Desktop\folder]: **Provider git is not
>   functional on this host**

Any idea what the problem is or how could i fix it?

Thank you a lot!

Gustavo B. Barbosa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error ("Provider git is not functional on this host") generally means that Puppet is unable to find the `git` command.  If `git` is installed, that probably means that the command is not in a directory that is in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: how do I fix this WITH PUPPET ? Can't get it fixed.. tried a lot

Comment: You could use puppet to install git, and then run puppet a second time.