# How do I set Windows environment paths in current Puppet session?

Tags: windows, git, puppet, chocolatey

I'm trying to install git and use it in the same puppet script

```
package { 'git':
  ensure => latest,
  provider => 'chocolatey',
}
vcsrepo { 'C:/':
  provider => git,
  source => 'github etc...',
}
```

However, I'm getting:

> Provider git is not functional on this host

The correct path is included in Environment Variables which leads me to believe that the error is just because the environment variables aren't updated.

The error disappears if I use `refreshenv` or `set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd"` on the command line or if I restart the command prompt, but **is there a way to update them in the same puppet script without manual intervention**?

I've tried adding the following to the .pp file (one at a time, of course):

```
#1
windows_env { 'PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\cmd': }

#2 (I've also tried different variations of quotes)
exec { 'temporary env var':
  path => 'C:/Windows/System32',
  command => 'cmd.exe /c "set \"PATH=$PATH%;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\""',
}

#3
exec { 'C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/refreshEnv.cmd': }
```

I guess you could say my question's an extension of  [Puppet agent: provider git is not functional on this host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658315/puppet-agent-provider-git-is-not-functional-on-this-host).

Comment: As you are seeing, this is somewhat a limitation in any Windows process, in that it won't automatically see environment updates (like PATH) and update themselves. Subprocesses are not able to update parent processes (that's why your different options all fail). I think you've determined the only way to do this until Puppet can support seeing and refreshing the environment automatically. https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-4708

Comment: @ferventcoder Thanks, I wasn't aware that it's not actually possible yet!

Comment: It's possible, You've seen it with `refreshenv`. It's just not something you can do with `vcsrepo` unless you can override path (you can in `exec`). So having Puppet do it automatically will help with that. That's what the ticket is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround that allows the puppet script to run fully.

Running `set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd"` in the command line before `puppet apply file.pp` sets git's future location as an environment variable just for the current command prompt (`set`, not `setx`). This way, when another command prompt is opened, the one-time path is gone, but the same path is added from the actual installation of git.